# What are the common sub-categories of computer RPG?

Tags: diablo-iii

I guess nobody would disagree that both [Hero Wars](https://hero-wars.fandom.com/wiki/Hero_Wars_Wiki) and [Diablo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diablo_(series)) are computer RPG but they are quite different. Which means there are more sub-categories which they belong to respectively, what are they? In other words, only consider the computer version, what are the common sub-categories of RPG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia has a list of [RPG Sub Genres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-playing_video_game#Subgenres):

- Action RPGs
- First-person party-based RPGs
- MMORPGs
- Roguelikes and roguelike-likes
- Sandbox RPGs
- Tactical RPGs
- Hybrid genres

In addition to this, RPGs can sometimes cross over into other genres; for example *Heroes of Might and Magic*:

> Although RPGs share some combat rules with wargames, RPGs are often about a small group of individual characters. Wargames tend to have large groups of identical units, as well as non-humanoid units such as tanks and airplanes. Role-playing games do not normally allow the player to produce more units. However, the Heroes of Might and Magic series crosses these genres by combining individual heroes with large numbers of troops in large battles.

Or *Warcraft 3: Reign of Chaos*:

> Warcraft III: Reign of Chaos, a real-time strategy game, features heroes that can complete quests, obtain new equipment, and "learn" new abilities as they advance in level. Multiplayer online battle arena (MOBA) genre, which is heavily inspired by the Warcraft III's mod Defense of the Ancients (DotA), is a fusion of role-playing games, real-time strategy games, and action games, with RPG elements built in its core gameplay. A key features, such as control over one character in a party, growth in power over the course of match, learning new thematic abilities, using of mana, leveling and accumulation of experience points, equipment and inventory management, completing quests, and fighting with the stationary boss monsters, have resemblance with role-playing games.